# Append rows from other tabs without losing formatting

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

In an effort to organize a set of bank account and credit card statements, I download them. Then I open them in Excel or Google Sheets, reorganize them in matching columns, put all in one tab (TOTAL), and then sort.

The question is now how I do the copy from the individual sheets. I think I'm pretty close after pasting and repeating (the manual way) some function I found by searching. The problem is that this function removes all formatting from the source rows

[Example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DiMjgVjrSCdki0N5L0V5L3Yzs9EALkINYAZ9qLb5kYQ/edit?usp=sharing)

The last tab `example_TOTAL` is put there only to show how I want tab `TOTAL` to look after the process is done.

Here's my function so far which does the most, but erases formatting (colors).

```
function Copy() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TabA'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:L'); //assign the range you want to copy
  var data = range.getValues();
  var ts = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TOTAL'); //replace with destination Sheet tab name
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TabB'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:L'); //assign the range you want to copy
  var data = range.getValues();
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TabC'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:L'); //assign the range you want to copy
  var data = range.getValues();
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);

  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TabD'); //replace with source Sheet tab name
  var range = ss.getRange('A1:L'); //assign the range you want to copy
  var data = range.getValues();
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
```

function copyFromTo() {

```
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TabA');
  var copy = ss.getRange('A1:L');

  var target = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TOTAL');
  var dest = target.getRange('A1:L');

  copy.copyTo(dest);
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TabB');
  var copy = ss.getRange('A1:L');
  copy.copyTo(dest);
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TabC');
  var copy = ss.getRange('A1:L');
  copy.copyTo(dest);
  var ss = spreadsheet.getSheetByName('TabD');
  var copy = ss.getRange('A1:L');
  copy.copyTo(dest);
```

}

How can I append from these sheets and still keep the formatting?

Comment: `copyTo`? As you state, `setValues` only transfers **values**

Comment: copyTo didn't append lines. Each tab was overwriting the next.

Comment: Edit your question to include how you used it. Sounds like you simply needed to change the target range.

Comment: I see now that I need to adjust range for "dest" (my copyTo script which I can't post as comment here now du to size limit. . Question is how. "A1" after first copy needs to be last empty row for the next SO I guyess I need to look into getLastRow or something similar with CopyTo.

Comment: Added my CopyTo function over. Error is obvious. But I'm not sure how to adjust to last row before each append/paste.

Comment: So first function above Copy() works but deletes all formatting. 
Second function copyFromTo() doesn't work because it overwrites previous rown copied. Error is obvious. Second function copies formatting too though.