# Copy rows from other tabs and merge in other

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-macros

I tried to ask a similar question here some days ago, but I guess my explanation was too complicated (link)[former post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52736092/copying-rows-from-other-tabs-and-pasteappend-on-result-tab).

I want to copy rows from 4 other tabs and append them to one summary-tab.

I have made a sheet to show what I need.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zYaiADwKx7YGD0zHkYvDVWNPzfRhF6wrexRB6Q8Xbs4/edit?usp=sharing

First tab named "TOTAL" should show a merge of all rows from TabA,TabB,TabC,TabD. The last tab "example_TOTAL" is just added there to show you how I want "TOTAL"-tab to look.
I have tried 2 sets of code to make it work:

1) The one included in former post (see link). PROBLEM: All formatting is lost during copy. Column B originally contains formatting.

2) Some code using .CopyTo . PROBLEM: new copy from other tab overwrites preview copy isteand of appending.

ANY HELP APPRECIATED!

Comment: You could use get and set numberformats too. Check the range section of the documentation. Your question reads like a set of requirements for someone else to a write a script for. If that’s your goal, good luck with that.

Comment: Re-asking a question is not how you request better answers (set a bounty instead). This may require you to contribute to the site and earn reputation first.

Comment: @cooper : I have made a script (see former post) but it doesn't copy the format. Just the pure content.

Comment: @tehhowch : sometimes when there's no response it's easy to assume that the question wasn't asked in a structures/understandable way. Hence trying to simplify.

Comment: Then you edit and improve your question, rather than ask an entirely new one that is the same?

Comment: @tehhowch you're right.

Comment: I looked at your previous example it uses getValues() and setValues() and as their name implies they only deal with the values of the cell and not formats.  So can you use other things like fontColors(), backgrounds() ...check out the range section of the spreadsheet documentation. Read it.Think about it.  Try to figure it out yourself. In the long run you'll learn a lot more by figuring it out yourself rather then getting someone elses answer.

Comment: If you run into problems try to break them down to smaller problems and work on them one at a time and when you can't figure it then return with a focused question. There's several volunteers on this site that have answered questions in minutes that I  have spent hours trying to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

In your case this would work.

```
=QUERY({TabA!A:K;TabB!A:K;TabC!A:K;TabD!A:K};"select * where Col1 is not null";0)
```

It doesn't transfer the colors.
I also added it in your google spreadsheet example.

Comment: OK. Thanks! But how do I put this in a script?

Comment: And how do I keep the formatting (colors/font) in column B?

Comment: w2lf said:"I also added it in your google spreadsheet example."
Ok. I moved i to suggestion_1 tab in case others wants to try as well.

Comment: Don't think you can.

Comment: This function wont work in script and it doesnt transfer the formats.
If you want that you will have to do it with scripts.

Comment: Check this and the Copy() script you already have.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyformattorangesheet-column-columnend-row-rowend

getBackground()
copyFormatToRange()

Comment: You know `QUERY`, but not `VLOOKUP`??

Comment: @w2lf OK. Thanks for your added help.

Comment: @I'-'I XD I don't know how I missed VLOOKUP and went straight for scripting.